# Percentile rank in R Not creating column

Tags: r

I am following this site to create percentile ranks in R. No "percent_rank" column is being created in the data frame - how would one add such a column to the data frame based on the below code?

https://www.statology.org/percentile-rank-in-r/

```
library(dplyr)

    #calculate percentile rank of points values

df %>%
  mutate(percent_rank = rank(points)/length(points))
```

Comment: You'd want `df <- df %>% mutate(...)`